# Permission denied error for running command on ubuntu

Tags: command-line, permissions

```
cd ~/mosesdecoder/sample-models
~/mosesdecoder/bin/moses -f phrase-model/moses.ini < phrase-model/in > out
```

I’m having an issue running this on the command line it gives me a permission denied error, is there anyway around it? I tried adding sudo in front but that didn't help, I'm a novice user trying to run a program on the command line and I tried doing it through the root level access but I am unable to locate this directory that way because it tries to do everything in the root directory.

Comment: you can do it with root by using cd / and then to your home directory .

Comment: Please edit your question and specify the exact error message after you run the command. Then we'll be able to help you better! :)

Comment: Probably the problem you are running into when you use `sudo` is that the shell is running `moses` as the superuser, but the redirects (`<` and `>`) are with your own privileges. I would login as the superuser with `sudo -i` and then `cd ~YOURUSERNAME` (so in my case, that would be `cd ~zpletan`).

Comment: Why should sudo be required when running from your own personal home directory?  Is root somehow the owner of the directory it's in, or the "phrase-model" directory?

Comment: Thank you all your suggestions helped me find my way to the solution.  SirCharlo the actual error was Permission Denied so thats why I didn't copy paste it.  The problem was that since I was logged in as root I was using the wrong syntax, removing the space after the '<' actually did the trick. Thank you all again.

Comment: @BrayanHernandez You found the solution, so I recommend posting your own answer to your question. (You can then even mark it as the accepted answer, after waiting two days.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I was running in root I was using ~ in my syntax and when in root that is not requires so I did it without any ~, and also removed a space after '<' and that did the job.